# Traefik issuing certificates for subdomains working fine, DigitalOcean certificate issued for domain

Tags: digital-ocean, traefik

I have a very weird situation going on, I've set up traefik to issue let's encrypt wild card certificates for my subdomains and my main domain, however, the main domains certificate is sometimes a valid let's encrypt cert and sometimes a non-valid "kubernetes" certificate issued by digital ocean (no idea where that comes from). Right now I'm using the acme staging server to not exceed rate limits so certs are currently not trusted which is perfectly fine, the problem is really about the issuer. On https://api.gogl.me the cert is from Fake LE just like https://traefik.sys.gogl.me but on https://gogl.me i'ts from DigitalOcean.

I don't understand why sometimes the cert is from one issuer and sometimes from the other. Traefik clearly picks up the host rule and redirects to the right container. I'm also using consul for storing the certs and I have also tried removing every service, even the volumes but to not avail.

traefik.toml

```
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "gogl.me"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.gogl.me"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.sys.gogl.me"
```

Service for gogl.me

```
web:
    image: customnginximage
    command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - default
      - traefik-public
    ports:
      - "80"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.backend=Web
        - traefik.tags=${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_TAG:-traefik-public}
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:gogl.me
        - traefik.port=80
        # Traefik service that listens to HTTP
        - traefik.redirectorservice.frontend.entryPoints=http
        - traefik.redirectorservice.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https
        # Traefik service that listens to HTTPS
        - traefik.webservice.frontend.entryPoints=https
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually fairly simple, instead of defining two acme domains (gogl.me and *.gogl.me) you have to define the wildcard domain as the main domain and the actual main domain as an alternative domain as stated here: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#wildcard-domains

So the configuration should look like this:

```
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.gogl.me"
  sans = ["gogl.me"]
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.sys.gogl.me"
```